# ScriptDB query entire DB and output to HTML table

Tags: google-apps-script

First, I'm a novice developer. I'm trying to create a basic Google Apps Script app that will use HTMLservice, take form data and store it in ScriptDB and have the ability to query the DB and display it in a table. The form is working OK as the logs show the objects being stored. However, when I try to query the entire DB I'm only getting one result returned. Here's the html:

> function queryResponse(responseObj){
>
> > ```
> >  $.each(responseObj, function(key, value) {
> >    $("#records").append(key + ': ' + value + "<br>");
> > });
> > ```
> >
> > }

Here's the script:

> function dumpData() {
>
> > ```
> > var results = db.query({});
> >  while (results.hasNext()) {
> >  var result = results.next();
> >  }
> >  Logger.log(result);
> >  return result;
> > ```
> >
> > }

My second question is once the entire DB is queried is it possible to display in a table? Any information would be appreciated.
Kind regards,
Mark

Comment: That first one isn't the HTML, it's the JQuery that appends some information to the item with an `id` of `#records`.

Comment: Have a look at this question and Serge's contributions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15310630/updating-html-table-instantly

Comment: @brbcoding - right, that's the JQuery code in my html file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your first question, your apps-script function is going through all the content of your `ScriptDB` and writing every value to a single `result`. When the loop completes, the final result - that is, the LAST object that returned by `db.query({})` - get returned. Just one.

Here's a modified version that returns an `Array` containing all objects.

```
function dumpData() {

  var results = db.query({});
  var result = [];
  while (results.hasNext()) {
    result.push (results.next());
  }
  Logger.log(result);
  return result;
}
```

### Building a Table

Now, about the second question.

Take a look at the [Building a Charts Dashboard](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/charts_dashboard) tutorial, for a good introduction to Charts Services. You may not be interested in a full Dashboard (multiple charts with the same underlying data), rather you are looking to create a lone TableChart, but the tutorial covers that.

If you're using apps-script, you'll create a UiApp, with a `doGet()` function that builds the TableChart. To populate your data source, you'll create a `newDataTable()`, add column headings according to your "keys" and their types, then add rows with the relevant "values". After that, it's a matter of creating your chart, binding the data to it, and attaching it to the UiApp.

Without any description of your actual data, that's about all the guidance I can offer.

Comment: Thank you, that helped. I was able to iterate through the array and output all of the query. Now I can work on the table. From what I read it looks like Chart services won't work with HTMLservice. Maybe I'll try it out with UIapp.

Answer (score 1):

As you asked for an HTMLService solution rather than UiApp, Mogsdad's approach using the UiApp will not help. You can  generate the table directly using a template file (following my comment above). However, if you then want to do things with the table (select rows, sort etc) as part of your larger application, consider using jQuery DataTable. A simple example is shown [here](http://davethinkingaloud.blogspot.co.nz/2013/03/jsonp-and-google-apps-script.html)

Comment: Thank you. I will check the question you linked above. I've used JQuery DataTables outside of Google Apps so I may give that a shot.